# How do I set an uneven ground on the background within Box2d?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

So I have a a problem with trying to create or set an uneven terrain for my sprite to move across on.

Currently I have a scrolling background using the same background image repeatedly alongside with gravity. However instead of having the bottom of the screen as my ground i would like to create set my own uneven terrain.

I tried using vertex helper to create this, but unfortunately that didn't seem to work. If anyone has any suggestions that would be great!

Comment: You can also look into PhysicsEditor, which helps in managing the physics in your application more than just the vertices of the sprite. Perhaps you can also try creating a box2d body with a special shape.

Answer (score 1):

I had a need to do this a while ago and found a great tutorial that gave me everything I needed.  Check out... http://www.raywenderlich.com/3888/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-part-1

It may be a little more than you are looking for, but it does go into detail about creating an uneven terrain.

Good luck.